# Does anyone have a sample of performing active authentication to Office 365 using ADFS 2.0 as the idP, without WIF?

Tags: windows-runtime, saml, adfs2.0, office365

I need this for a Metro Style app, which can't use Passive authentication, and doesn't have WIF.

So far I've managed to get a SAML token from ADFS 2.0. 
I now need to send this token to login.MicrosoftOnline.com, which will return me an SWT token to give to [mysite].sharepoint.com, which will give me cookies to include with REST requests.

ADFS 2.0 and login.MicrosoftOnline both talk WS-Trust. I've found *many* samples on the web that shows how to send the token request to MicrosoftOnline, but they all rely on sending the username and password along. In this case, however, MicrosoftOnline doesn't have permission to authenticate the password directly. My only option is to give it the SAML token.

The username and password I'm using works fine when using passive authentication, so the credentials is not the problem.

Samples can be in any language (except klingon), but .Net is preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late, I did not see your question until today. I did manage to send a saml token to Sharepoint online with this code (using usr/pwd): http://sharepointwinrt.codeplex.com/

Maybe it will give a starting point for you.

Cheers,

Juanma

Comment: It seems to lack the ADFS 2.0 part, but I've figured that one out and it just follows (approximately) the same pattern as you have here, with different xml templates, since we're dealing with regular soap services.